# Python(BeautifulSoup) - Get href from <script>

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm working on "Video Downloader" and I have one problem with BeautifulSoup4.

Here is part of html which from I want to get a href:

```
<script src="/static/common.js?v7"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
            var c = 6;
            window.onload = function() {
                count();
            }

            function closeAd(){
                $("#easy-box").hide();
            }

            function notLogedIn(){
                $("#not-loged-in").html("You need to be logged in to download this movie!");
            }

            function count() {
                if(document.getElementById('countdown') != null){
                    c -= 1;
                    //If the counter is within range we put the seconds remaining to the <span> below 
                    if (c >= 0) 
                        if(c == 0){
                            document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = '';
                        }
                        else {
                            document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = c; 
                        }
                    else {
                        document.getElementById('download-link').innerHTML = '<a style="text-decoration:none;" href="http://s896.vshare.io/download,9999999999999999999999999999999999999999-f6192405453bf5ff3cfe41a488d8390d,5944ed28,4d948c5.avi">Click here</a> to download requested file.';
                        return;
                    }           
                    //setTimeout('count()', 1000);
                }
            }
        </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/flowplayer/flowplayer-3.2.13.min.js"></script>
```

And here is href which I want to print:

```
href="http://s896.vshare.io/download,9999999999999999999999999999999999999999-f6192405453bf5ff3cfe41a488d8390d,5944ed28,4d948c5.avi"
```

I was trying with this, but it's not working.

```
for a in soup3.find_all('a'):
    if 'href' in a.attrs:
        print(a['href'])
```

Comment: The href is inside the javascript. You could grab the js part and extract the href with the help of [regex](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html). Have a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24333189/parsing-js-with-beautiful-soup)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Beautiful Soup can parse HTML and XML, not JavaScript.
You can use regular expression to search this code.
Using `<a [^>]*?(href=\"([^\">]+)\")` you can match everything inside this code which:

- `<a` - is an `a` tag
- `[^>]*?` - can have any characters that are not `>`
- `href="` - have href
- `[^\">]+` - have any number of characters other than `"` and `>`

To extract script code from html you can use
`script = soup.find('script', {'type': 'text/javascript'})`
and then to parse it, use
`re.search(r"<a [^>]*?(href=\"([^\">]+)\")", script.text)`
Remember to `import re` first.

```
print(re.search(r"<a [^>]*?(href=\"([^\">]+)\")", script.text)[1])
# href="http://s896.vshare.io/download,9999999999999999999999999999999999999999-f6192405453bf5ff3cfe41a488d8390d,5944ed28,4d948c5.avi
print(re.search(r"<a [^>]*?(href=\"([^\">]+)\")", script.text)[2])
# http://s896.vshare.io/download,9999999999999999999999999999999999999999-f6192405453bf5ff3cfe41a488d8390d,5944ed28,4d948c5.avi
```

Read about regular expression. If you are going to use pattern often, compile it first.
https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html

Comment: Thank you for answer, but I have got an error: `print(re.search(r"<a [^>]*?(href=\"([^\">]+))\"", script.text)[1])
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'`

Comment: Looks like BS have not found any `script`. Are you sure you used proper parameters to `soup.find()` function?

Comment: Now I've got this error `print(re.search(r"<a [^>]*?(href=\"([^\">]+))\"", script.text)[1])
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable`

Comment: This probably means that regex didn't find anything matching. Are you sure that 'script' contains what regex should match?

Comment: I'm sure. Here is website which from I want to get href: http://vshare.io/d/4d948c5

Comment: It's because there are multiple scripts on this site, and the 3rd script is the only 1 containing this link. You have to filter it. If it's always 3rd, you can use `scripts = soup.find_all('script', {'type': 'text/javascript'})      
print(re.search(r"<a [^>]*?(href=\"([^\">]+))", scripts[2].text)[1])`